# Unity Rewarded Ads

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityads

How do i keep track of the amount of ads the player has watched, then reward the player when he has watched a certain amount of ads , e.g. 3 ads watched rewards the player the unlock of all levels or a certain amount of coins.

```
public Button[] lvlButtons;

    void Start()
    {
        int levelAt = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("levelAt", 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < lvlButtons.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i + 2 > levelAt)
                lvlButtons[i].interactable = false;
        }
        
    }
```

This is my Code that locks levels.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to approach this.
The most simple is to save with `PlayerPrefs` the amount of successfull watched ads and just increment the number, and after you reward the player you can simply set the amount back to 0 in order to reset the counting.

Comment: Could you guide me with the code. Im guessing i have to store variables but idk how.